# Find and append new string next to it

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, grep

need unix command to find and append new string right next to it

I tried this:

```
sed -i '/old_string/ a\ new_string \' temp
```

Output:

```
old_string
 new_string
```

Output needed:

```
old_string new_string
```

Answer (score 4):

Just "replace old_string with old_string and new_string":

```
sed -i~ 's/old_string/old_string new_string/' temp
```

which you can shorten to

```
sed -i~ 's/old_string/& new_string/' temp
```

where `&` stands for "the entire matched string".

Answer (score 2):

Use `sed` like this:

```
sed 's/hi/& there/'
```

to replace `hi` with `the search string` plus `there` without re-typing the search string

```
echo "hi my friend" | sed 's/hi/& there/'
hi there my friend
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
sed -i 's/old/& new/' file
```